# Angular 8 deployment issue: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input error

Tags: angular

I recently upgraded my Angular CLI project from Angular 5 to 8.1.1.  ng serve is running correctly and I'm able to run ng build --prod with no errors.  However, after I transfer the files in the dist folder to my root folder using Filezilla and load my URL on chrome and firefox on windows or safari on ios, I'm getting this error inside Chrome's console:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
main-es2015.d77d00c60d6680c15698.js:1*

The project is running successfully on IE and I believe that's due to the fact that IE is using the main-es5 file.  Also, sometimes the project will load once and then fail on refresh on chrome/firefox/safari.

If I build for prod like this...

*ng build --prod --build-optimizer --base-href "/subfolder/" --deploy-url "/subfolder/"*

...the project successfully runs on Chrome and other browsers on that url using a subfolder.  Example:  www.test.com/subfolder.  But I need to release to production on www.test.com and running ng build --prod gives me that Uncaught SyntaxError inside the browser's console.

I'm using the tsconfig from the angular deployment documentation (https://angular.io/guide/deployment) in the tsconfig in the project's root:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you on Windows uploading to Linux?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: Try uploading the files as "binary" in Filezilla. I believe that Angular/Webpack builds the bundles with Linux linebreaks as default, and Filezilla might be trying to modify the files during upload. This is just a guess by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  But it didn't work.  It doesn't explain why it would work successfully when targeting the subfolders.  I'll keep trying different things.

Comment: @brettvay we have the exact same issue. Can you please tell us whether you fixed it and how?

Comment: Has anyone solved this?

Comment: deployment env issue.